# Unable to open iMovie

Tags: imovie

I'm trying to open the iMovie app on my Macbook, but it has an X on the icon and when I click on it, it tells me I to upgrade the app in order to get into it. In the Mac App Store, I checked for new updates, and indeed there is a new update for iMovie (along with iPhoto and Keynote updates). To do the updates, I pressed `update all`, but only the iPhoto and Keynote updates actually happened (the iMovie update is stuck loading) My computer freezes and fails to update iMovie.

**How can I get iMovie to open?**

*Edit:* The update is to iMovie 10.1.4

Comment: What type and OS is your Mac? Go to the  button in the menubar and hit "About This Mac". Then comment back `@Owlswipe` so I can help you some more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Damaged and can't be open app error message](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58050/damaged-and-cant-be-open-app-error-message)